# If meaning of a word able to vary by sentence, what does it mean by alone?

Tags: meaning

So I mean there are too many words which is multiple meaning in English. And these sentences are able to vary by sentence. For example:

> The house by the tree.

"by" means "next to" or "near"

> This book was written by a popular author.

"by" means "product of".

What does these words mean when we use them by alone? When does "by, as, about, so" mean different? What is the basic meanings of these words?

Comment: The word "by" would never be used alone - it requires context to have meaning.

Comment: Thanks. What about rest of?

Comment: I don't think it is possible to say what they mean "alone".  They have several possible meanings, and they only have a specific meaning in a specific context.

Comment: @stangdon what is the specific contexts?

Comment: @user123960 The specific context means "the sentence that they are used in."

Comment: Thanks @stangdon but I tried to mean: is there rule to get specific meaning?

Comment: @user123960  The only rule is "look at it in context".

Answer (score 1):

In many languages there are many words whose meaning depends on the context in which they occur.

These words do not have a single "basic meaning". A good dictionary will tell you when there are several meanings, and illustrate each with a sentence or two. Your examples demonstrate that for "by" in English. Sometimes the several meanings are related, sometimes not.

That is part of what makes learning a new language difficult.

Comment: Thanks. As far as I understand _by, as, so, about_ doesn't have meaning by alone. Right?

Comment: Look up these words in a dictionary, and you will see lists of the various ways in which they can be used.

Answer (score 0):

Some English words may have **many different** meanings, depending on **context**. For example:

- She is running the race.
- The car is running out of gas.
- His nose is running.
- She is running for office.
- The producer is running the show.

Another example:

- The gas is unionized. [No atoms have gained or lost electrons.]
- The company is unionized. [Employees have joined together to form a union.]

That is why English dictionaries give a **list** of definitions. No, English is *not* an easy language to learn. Perhaps [Esperanto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Esperanto) or other synthetic language would be easier to learn, but it is not very widely used.

Comment: Thanks. What if I use _by, as, about, so_ by alone? Does it have mean?

Comment: Comparing un-ionized and union-ized is clever, but doesn't really contribute to this otherwise correct answer.